# How to determine if an automated functional test was successful

Tags: testing, tdd, functional-testing

**Goal:**

- Determine if a functional test was successful.

**Scenario:**

- We have a functional requirement: "A user should be able to signup with username and password. The username has to be a valid email-adress. The password has to be at least 8 characters long".
- We have a method "SignupResult UserManager.Signup(string username, string password)".
- We want a happy-test with valid intputs, and a sad-test with invalid inputs.
- Sub-Systems of the UserManager (e.g. Database) can be either mocked or real systems.

**Question:**
What would be the best way to determine if the user was successfully signed up. I can imagine the following options:

- If any of the sub-system was mocked, one could check if a specific function like "DB.SaveUser(...)" was called. This would destroy the idea of a functional test being a blackbox test and requires that the test-writer has knowledge of the implementation.
- If we use real sub-systems, one could for example check if the row in the DB exists. That would be not adequate like the attempt above.
- One could use another function like "UserManager.CheckUser(...)" to check if the user was created. This would introduce another method that is tested, also there may be operations that would have no "test-counterpart", or one would have to implement them, just for testing - that seems not ideal.
- We could check the result "SignupResult" and/or check for exceptions thrown. This would require defining the interface of the method. This also would require all methods to return a sensible value - I guess this will be a good approach anyway.

To me the last methods seems to be the way to go. Am I correct? Are there other approaches? How would we check side-effects like "an email was sent to the new user" ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to acquaint yourself with the concept of the [Test Pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html).

There's no single correct way to design and implement automated tests - only [trade-offs](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/29/Feedbackmechanismsandtradeoffs).

If you absolutely must avoid any sort of knowledge of implementation details, there's really only way to go about it: test the actual system.

The problem with that is that automated tests tend to leave behind a trail of persistent state changes. For example, I once did something like what you're asking about and wrote a series of automated tests that used the actual system (a REST API) to sign up new users.

The operations people soon asked me to turn that system off, even though it only generated a small fraction of actual users.

You might think that the next-best thing would be a full systems test against some staging or test environment. Yes, but then you have to take it on faith that this environment sufficiently mirrors the actual production environment. How can you know that? By knowing something about implementation details. I don't see how you can avoid that.

If you accept that it's okay to know *a little* about implementation details, then it quickly becomes a question of how much knowledge is acceptable.

The experience behind the test pyramid is that unit tests are much easier to write and maintain than integration tests, which are again easier to write and maintain than systems tests.

I usually find that the sweet spot for these kinds of tests are [self-hosted](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2021/01/25/self-hosted-integration-tests-in-aspnet) [state-based tests](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/18/from-interaction-based-to-state-based-testing) where only the actual system dependencies such as databases or email servers are replaced with Fakes (not Mocks).

Comment: So you would prefer inspection (via mock/fake) over a public API to check if the code under test produced the required behaviour?

Comment: @MichaelRall As outlined in the linked articles, I'd write tests that interact and verify via the system's public interface, but with database and other real system dependencies replaced with Fakes (*not* Mocks).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the requirement that needs further refinement.
For instance, what precisely would your user do to verify if she has signed up correctly? How would she know? I imagine she'd look at the response from the system: "account successfully created". Then she'd only know that the system posts a message in response to that valid creation attempt.
Testing for the posted message is actionable, just having a created account is not. This is acceptable as a more specific test, at a lower test level.

So think about *why* exactly users should register? Just to see response? How about the requirement:

*When a user signs up with a valid username and a valid password, then she should be able to successfully log into the system using the combination of that username and password.*

Then one can add a definition of a successful login, just like the definitions of validity of the username and password.

This is actionable, without knowing specifics about internals. It should be acceptable as far as system integration tests go.

Comment: Hey, good points, for me it's still hard to get the feature/requirement and then to the test that really nails down what should be achieved. I'm often a step further, because "we solved this problem 10 times so and so".


To focus on the things that need to be achieved until it's really boiled down is the goal.


To take my example, I would have other requirements like "user should confirm via email" - but the starting point is always "a user has to log in to use the system" and then we go further.